# use css variable to generate class names in scss

Tags: css, angular, sass

is it possible to generate class names by css variables?

I am using scss in angular and I want to generate my class names base on

```
@input color
```

property of component

so I store the input in a css variable named --color-variable to use it in my scss file.
I want to do something like this:

```
.ps-button--color-#{var(--color-variable)}{}
```

this is the compiler error:

[image]

any suggestions would be helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to generate class names by css variables?

**Short answer:**

No.

**Longer answer:**

CSS custom properties, also commonly called CSS variables, are known at runtime, while SASS variables are known at compile time. Since browsers can't understand SASS, it first needs to be compiled down to CSS and by that time, the SASS compiler won't know what the value of the CSS variable will be, so it throws a compile error.

**Possible solution**

Dynamically generate CSS based on your input and add it to the DOM.

Comment: Good answer but the possible solution might be simpler than that. Depends on what you want Mohsen. If you got a list of colors already then you can do it by using sass variables and loop.

Comment: @Dejan.S True :) but that is why I said _possible solution_ as the OP did not specify its ultimate goal.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I am using tailwind. so I wanted to generate class names on compile time.
but it seems that the css variables are runtime variables.
so I guess I should have generate classes either in .ts file or in my html file.